# cmd.exe start error with links

Tags: windows, command-line, internet, cmd.exe

Whenever I type in cmd the command:  `start "" "http://www.google.com"`
I get a error window with the title "http://www.google.com" and text:

```
http://google.com
Application not found
```

[image: Pic]
And if I close that (or press the OK button) `Permission denied` appears in the Console.
So how do I fix that so that I can open links with the normal start command again.

Comment: Have you tried to execute CMD as administrator? I can't reproduce your error at all.

Comment: which windows version (screenshot looks like 10)? for me it works in windows 8 and opens the default browser (IE)

Comment: Windows 10, Default Browser: Chrome, that should automatically update

Comment: @duDe tryed that but has the same effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check and adjust your Windows default program settings.  This article shows you how to do that (for the same error you're experiencing):

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/application-not-found-error-mail-http-url/

Comment: Tryed that but didn't work, but i noticed that the chrome icon in that list is not the normal one, is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Do you know which icon it is?  Are Chrome and Windows both up to date?

Comment: the Icon is like it is not installed/no icon is set (in system32 you can find loads of exe files with that icon) and Chrome and Windows automatically update so it should be newest version

Comment: Weird.  Do you have another browser installed?  Can you try making that browser your default browser and then seeing if the `start` command works?  Might help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Works with everything except chrome. tryed microsoft edge, internet explorer and other file types

Comment: I don't have Chrome on this computer but have it on another, I'll try some things and see if I can duplicate the problem

Comment: @ShulkerHD could not duplicate the problem on my Win7 PC with Chrome.  Are you able to uninstall and reinstall it?  Not sure if that will fix it but it's worth a try.

Comment: @ShulkerHD just out of curiosity, if you double click on an HTML file, like in a Windows folder, does it open in Chrome, with no problem?

Comment: I cant open html files but reinstalling did it now it works again